# Can you use Azure Key Vault Generated Certificates to Authenticate Azure IoT Hub devices?

Tags: azure, certificate, azure-keyvault, azure-iot-hub

So apart from SAS-Keys I can choose Self-Signed and CA-Signed Certificates as an authentication method and the Azure Key Vault can no also generate Certificates.
I did not find a way to use the generated certificates from the Azure Key Vault to authenticate my Azure IoT Hub Devices. Is / should this be possible?

Answer (score 1):

Azure IOT devices support only three authentication type with IOT hub

1. [Symmetric key authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/how-to-authenticate-downstream-device?view=iotedge-2020-11#symmetric-key-authentication)
2. [X.509 self-signed authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/how-to-authenticate-downstream-device?view=iotedge-2020-11#x509-self-signed-authentication)
3. [X.509 CA-signed authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/how-to-authenticate-downstream-device?view=iotedge-2020-11#x509-ca-signed-authentication)

[image]

You can store the root CA certificate and device primary and Secondary certificate and Key generated by above authentication in Azure Key Vault for the security purpose, but you cannot use the certificate that is self generated by Key Vaul and even you cannot directly use certificate from Key Vault you have to put or download and update them in a folder of your IOT Edge. From IOT Edge you can use in your IOT devices.

You can refer this GITHUB discussion for more clarification: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/48565

Comment: So what should be used when you want to generate and use certificates for many IoT Device, track their lifetime and regenerate when the expire.
Is there nothing like DigiCert inside of Azure?

Comment: For Generating and use Certificate Please do Refers this MS document : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/tutorial-x509-self-sign
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/tutorial-x509-scripts

Comment: You can manage certificate in IOT edge devices.Once you configure Certicate with IOTedge with new certificate.This certificate expires after 90 days but is automatically renewed before expiring. You can also configure the expiration date . Please refer this MS document as well for the same: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/how-to-manage-device-certificates?view=iotedge-2020-11&tabs=windows

Comment: Hey I know this script and have used it but as it is stated these are not production certificates and do not help

Comment: are you using Production Certificate or Testing Certificate?

Comment: What is the best way to generate and manage Iot Device Certificates (CA, Intermediate and Device Certificates) on a production level (100+ Devices). If Azure KeyVault can be used for that or other external services like DigiCert has to be used

Comment: Lets Have chat over here : https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239447/can-you-use-azure-key-vault-generated-certificates-to-authenticate-azure-iot-hub

Comment: Don't have enough reputation for that :/

Comment: No Problem.  Will get back to you with answer over here only. Allow me time by tomorrow.

Comment: yeah sure no stress

Comment: @HarounS. hi, have you managed to solve this issue? I'm also looking for the easiest way to generate, manage and track device certificates.

Comment: @BlackMiracle Hey, no it is not possible to generate and manage device certificates with the Azure Key Vault. Really missing a feature here, because in AWS there is the possibility to easily create and manage X.509 Certificates right from the "portal". You might have to use other Services such as digicert :/